# runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference, again

Tags: go

I am trying to use the mysqlstore backend package for gorilla sessions in a Golang web application. I am following [this example](https://github.com/srinathgs/mysqlstore) and my code is identical. The code builds and runs fine but when I go to localhost:8080/ in my browser I am getting this error

> runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Here is my code:

```
package main

  import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/srinathgs/mysqlstore"
    "net/http"
  )

  var store *mysqlstore.MySQLStore

  func sessTest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    session, err := store.Get(r, "foobar")
    session.Values["bar"] = "baz"
    session.Values["baz"] = "foo"
    err = session.Save(r, w)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", session)
    fmt.Println(err)
  }

func main() {

    store, err := mysqlstore.NewMySQLStore("root:mypass@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/mydb?parseTime=true&loc=Local", "sessions", "/", 3600, []byte("<SecretKey>"))
    if err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }
    defer store.Close()

        http.HandleFunc("/", sessTest)
        http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Here is the full error message:

> 2019/02/12 02:46:43 http: panic serving [::1]:63119: runtime error:
>   invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference goroutine 34
>   [running]: net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc000112320)
>     /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11.5/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1746 +0xd0
>   panic(0x12c9f40, 0x1560950)
>     /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.11.5/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:513 +0x1b9
>   github.com/srinathgs/mysqlstore.(*MySQLStore).New(0x0, 0xc000138000,
>   0x1324045, 0x6, 0x158afa0, 0xc00010a000, 0xb)
>     /Users/Mark/go/src/github.com/srinathgs/mysqlstore/mysqlstore.go:137
>   +0xef github.com/gorilla/sessions.(*Registry).Get(0xc00011e0e0, 0x1376e20, 0x0, 0x1324045, 0x6, 0xc00010c100, 0x0, 0x1)
>     /Users/Mark/go/src/github.com/gorilla/sessions/sessions.go:139 +0x142
>   github.com/srinathgs/mysqlstore.(*MySQLStore).Get(0x0, 0xc000138000,
>   0x1324045, 0x6, 0x1086222, 0xc00010a044, 0xc00010a050)
>     /Users/Mark/go/src/github.com/srinathgs/mysqlstore/mysqlstore.go:131
>   +0x63 main.sessTest(0x13770a0, 0xc00013c000, 0xc000138000)    /Users/Mark/go/src/testsessions/main.go:12 +0x61
>   net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x133a680, 0x13770a0, 0xc00013c000,
>   0xc000138000)
>
> <…>

Comment: The question may have been asked before but the circumstances and solution are completely different. I saw the "duplicate" and it gave me no clue as to how to solve my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the `store` that you are creating in your main func is not being assigned to the global `store`. The global store being used in your handler is still nil. This is because of how the `:=` operator works, and the fact that you are trying to assign to a var declared elsewhere.

You could either

1. assign to the global store correctly by not using the `:=` and declaring `var err error` above that line
   e.g.

```
var err error
store, err = mysqlstore.NewMySQLStore(...
```

2. Or the way that i recommend (without global vars) is to: initialize `store` in main as you have done, and also initialize your handler by wrapping the handler function in a closure and passing the store into that

e.g.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/srinathgs/mysqlstore"
    "net/http"
)

// note: this returns a http.HandlerFunc, which works because
// http.HandlerFunc is just a named type for a function which accepts http.ResponseWriter and *http.Request as args
// see the docs at https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc
// (but yea at the end of the day, this is a function which returns another function)
func makeSessTest(store *mysqlstore.MySQLStore) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        session, err := store.Get(r, "foobar")
        session.Values["bar"] = "baz"
        session.Values["baz"] = "foo"
        err = session.Save(r, w)
        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", session)
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}

func main() {
    store, err := mysqlstore.NewMySQLStore("root:mypass@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/mydb?parseTime=true&loc=Local", "sessions", "/", 3600, []byte("<SecretKey>"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer store.Close()

    http.HandleFunc("/", makeSessTest(store))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Comment: As a newbie I'd really appreciate a code example for that.

Comment: @markhorrocks sure, see my edit